# Line under navbar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I draw a line under navbar when scrolling in React or JavaScript. Like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01hZ3.png)

Comment: I'd recommend using one of the many existing implementations of this rather than building your own; search for "page scroll progress" or "reading progress indicator"

Answer (score 1):

Easy to use scroll listener and progress element.

```js
const progressDOM = document.querySelector("#progress");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  let docHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  let winHeight = window.innerHeight;
  let scrollPercent = scrollTop / (docHeight - winHeight);
  let scrollPercentRounded = Math.round(scrollPercent * 100);
  progressDOM.value = scrollPercentRounded;
});
```

```css
#progress{

  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progress" max="100" value="0"></progress>

<div style="height: 10000px;"></div>
```

Comment: how can I do that in react under navbar <div></div>

Answer (score 0):

- it's easy in your script file use `scroll` event

> Example

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
   //Select your navigation bar
   var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
   //Change 20 to anything you want like nav.offsetHeight
   if(window.scrollY > 20) {
       nav.style.borderBottom = "5px solid dodgerblue";
    } else {
      nav.style.border = "0";
   }
});
```